# Update String with parameters

Tags: java, string, parameters, java-8

I'm using Spring with Java 8.

I have a string with parameters and I am not sure how should I updates the parameters by list of params.

```
 String message = "Today is {0} and {1} is happy";
 List<String> params = Arrays.asList("Sunday", "Uri", "Dan");
```

I would like to know with which operator should I use in order to get :

```
  String newMessage = "Today is Sunday and Uri is happy.";
```

Thanks you

Comment: Please make an attempt.

Comment: @Logan. That is probably not going to figure in a comprehensive solution directly.

Comment: Not really related to `Spring` but if `params` would be `String[]` (you can easily create it) you could use `java.text.MessageFormat.format`

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you. I will try. I actually saw now a solution with String.format . I will try both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you have got accurate answer to your exact requirement. But MessageFormat is very dangerous and not flexible enough where you have to repeat value replacement. So, for example, you want output string as `Today is Sunday and Uri is happy. Also, Uri is going to party today.`

Now, MessageFormat code would be like below:

```
 String message = "Today is {0} and {1} is happy. Also, {2} is going to party today.";
 List<String> params = Arrays.asList("Sunday", "Uri", "Uri");
 String result = MessageFormat.format(message, params.toArray());
```

It's a risky code for following reasons:

1. What if you actually need something for example like `{test}` or `{}` in string itself? It's going to fail.
2. For repeating values you have to manage your Array with duplicate entries and ensure the right order.
3. It's really is not readable if string grows.

A better solution hence is to use  `StrSubstitutor` as below:

```
    String template = "Today is ${day} and ${name} is happy";
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("day", "Sunday");
    data.put("name", "Uri");
    System.out.println(StrSubstitutor.replace(template, data));
```

Notice that how named values are replaced. It's just like choosing between `?` or `named parameters` in SQL queries.

`StrSubstitutor` comes from `log4j` framework.

Hence, please make the right choice as per your need.

Cheers!

Comment: It's from log4j. I find it very handy. Updated my answer.

Comment: Is this matter whether StrSubstitutor is being import from org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor?

Comment: I think apache commons is developed by apache and is a utility  for common operations and functionality. And you should quickly check through API that what is it's implementation. As I believe there could be some deviations from what log4j provides. Though log4j is a common logging framework and hence if you want to use apache commons, there should be other strong reasons for same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) like this :

```
String result = MessageFormat.format(message, params.toArray());
```

**Output**

```
Today is Sunday and Uri is happy
```